# Rotations about the origin

Tags: matrices, rotations

Let R(θ) denote a rotation
matrix which rotates a point $x$ in $S^2$ anticlockwise about the origin through a given angle
θ.  (Where $S$ is the set of real numbers)

How do you illustrate that this preserves lines, distances and angles by rotating the triangle with vertices (1, 2),(2, 8),(3, 2) through an angle $π/2$?

Comment: can you build a matrix for the rotation through the angle $\pi/2$?

Comment: so i would make a matrix for the triangle with x values for the first column and y values for the second column?  then multiply it by R(θ)?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean, I will provide a solution below and see if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general form for a two dimensional rotation matrix is
$\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$

Plugging in your value of $\pi/2$, we get:
$\begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}$

You should try and convince yourself this makes intuitive sense by applying it to $e_{1}$ and $e_{2}$ and seeing what it does (remember that a matrix or linear map is defined by what it does to basis vectors) or better yet, apply it to the three points that are the vertices of your triangle, and see what it does.